# Change in recent Swift update regarding mutating structs?

Tags: swift

I am following along in the Stanford iOS course and I have a question that I believe is related to a recent update. Here is the section of code:

```
func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?,remainingOps: [Op]) {
    let op = ops.removeLast() //*I thought ops was immutable?         
}
```

On the video, the instructor gets an error that says you cannot do this because ops is immutable. This makes complete sense but when I try typing this in I do not get an error. What does this mean? Is this a change in a recent Swift update that structs passed into methods are mutable? Any ideas? In the video, the instructor solves the problem by creating an instance variable which is a copy of ops but I no longer get the error and would like to understand why this is.

*EDIT* When typing this into a playground I still get the error but I do not in my Swift File. For reference here is the entire file so far. Any ideas? I just want to understand what is going on here:

```
import Foundation

class CalculatorBrain {

    private enum Op {
        case Operand(Double)
        case UnaryOperation(String,Double -> Double)
        case BinaryOperation(String, (Double,Double) -> Double)
    }

    private var opStack = [Op]()

    private var knownOps = [String:Op]()

    init() {
        knownOps["×"] = Op.BinaryOperation("×",*)
        knownOps["÷"] = Op.BinaryOperation("÷") { $1 / $0 }
        knownOps["+"] = Op.BinaryOperation("+",+)
        knownOps["−"] = Op.BinaryOperation("−") { $1 - $0 }
        knownOps["^"] = Op.BinaryOperation("^") { pow($1,$0) }
        knownOps["√"] = Op.UnaryOperation("√",sqrt)
        knownOps["sin"] = Op.UnaryOperation("sin") { sin($0) }
        knownOps["cos"] = Op.UnaryOperation("cos") { cos($0) }
        knownOps["tan"] = Op.UnaryOperation("tan") { tan($0) }

    }

    func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?,remainingOps: [Op]) {
        if !ops.isEmpty {
            let op = ops.removeLast()//*Error should appear here but does not

        }
        return (nil,ops)
    }

    func evaluate() -> Double? {

    }

    func pushOperand(operand: Double) {
        opStack.append(Op.Operand(operand))
    }

    func performOperation(symbol: String) {
        if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {
            opStack.append(operation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I'm on Xcode 6.3.1 and I've just tried putting in the func along with creating an Op struct in a Playground and I get the following error "Immutable value of type '[Op]' only has mutating members named 'removeLast'"

Comment: Please see the edit above

Comment: Turns out it was a bug as @Salihcyilmaz suggested below. I restarted Xcode and now it comes up as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked to see if it implicitly makes copy of array. No it does not. Your xCode is in bug i think. Please restart xCode and try again. Go to utilities bar, move your cursor on ops array in the code. What do you observe as a type? `"error type"` or something else? You can also check this by pressing `opt` and click to the variable.

Comment: As you suggested, I restarted Xcode and now it does show up as an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this now with the following Playground code which throws up an error (Xcode 6.3.1):

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCPlayground

//: Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift 3. Applying MVC 40 minutes in

enum Op {
    case Operand(Double)
    case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
}

var knownOps = [String:Op]()

knownOps["x"] = Op.BinaryOperation("x", *)

// by putting let for the parameter we are declaring ops as immutable
// the default is for each parameter is let
func evaluate(ops: [Op]) -> (result: Double?, remainingOps: [Op]) {
    if !ops.isEmpty {
        let op = ops.removeLast() // Immutable value of type '[Op]' only has mutating members named 'removeLast'
    }
    return (nil, ops)
}
```

if I change `evaluate(ops: [Op])` to `evaluate(var ops: [Op])`, the same as in the video it removes the error. I'm thinking that there is something wrong with the Xcode project you are using - maybe try restarting Xcode (the old off 'n on)?